# Crash after using getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app crashes after using getSharedPreferences, AndroidRuntime

at `android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)`

I don't know how to fix this, can someone help me?

Here is the code of where it crashes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Answer extends Activity{
    boolean answered;
    int id;
    String Answer;
    String Pref = Question.Pref;

    public LogoItem(int i){
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = i;
        answered = pref.getBoolean("answered", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your **onCreate(...)** method?

Comment: @M D 
There is no onCreate, do I need it?

Comment: the error is in the class ContextWrapper.java@ line no:146. Pls check that line of code or upload that

Comment: `public LogoItem(int i)`. A method without return??? Put your real code

Comment: @PankajKumar 


    questions = new ArrayList<Answer>();

     questions.add(new LogoItem(i));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Proper **Context** for `getSharedPreferences(...)` . and

here in your code if Answer is an **Activity** then you need to override `onCreate(...)` method and if not then you need to create single argument `Constructor` and pass **context** and then used `getSharedPreferences(...)`